# Can't view public folder as contact in Outlook 2010 with SBS exchange 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

We have been using Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007 to view public business contact lists from our exchange based window SBS 2003.

The other day a computer died and I acquired another.  I went online to Amazon and ordered a "to cheap copy of Outlook 2010".  I had never experienced outlook 2010 and figured it wouldn't be much different than outlook 2007, I was wrong!
Also Couldn't figure why it was only $50 and not $100+.  It shows up and it turns out it's a student version well I use it.  So the secretary can view her personal contacts in business card format but her the public folder of contacts just displays like email now on outlook 2010.  The views tab in outlook 2010 only shows views which select email like items like subject, from, to.

I do a bunch of searching online and play a lot but I get nowhere.
I find this info about changes in outlook 2010
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179110.aspx
Under 2010 Outlook changes I find
"Current View and Organize panes   The Current View pane in the navigation pane for Contacts, Tasks, and Notes is removed in Outlook 2010. Also the Ways to Organize Inbox pane, which you accessed in Office Outlook 2007 by clicking Tools and Organize, is removed in Outlook 2010. You can change and format your views by using the features on the ribbon View tab."

So this says I can use the view tab but I still can't get the contacts view I had on outlook 2010 with the public contact info.

So I figure it's either because I need the Business Contact Manager which I don't have, or outlook 2010 is just crap, or there is some totally obscure way to fix this I don't know.

So HELP!

Comment: I upvoted all your questions so you can vote yourself.